# Remove elements in `array` from `<select>`

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<select>` element which is rendered from an `array` with some vehicles in it.

When I choose a vehicle and add it to another array, I want it to *not* be displayed in the `<select>` element. However, I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Here is my current code:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

 $scope.chosenTags = [];
 $scope.tags = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Ford', type: 'Car' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Open', type: 'Car' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Ferrari', type: 'Car' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Mountain', type: 'Bike' },
  { id: 5, name: 'BMX', type: 'Bike' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Racing', type: 'Bike' },
 ];
 $scope.currentTag = $scope.tags[0];

 $scope.addTag = function() {
  $scope.chosenTags.push($scope.currentTag);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<select ng-model="currentTag" id="tags" ng-options="tag.name group by tag.type for tag in tags"></select>
<button ng-click="addTag()">Add</button>

<hr />

<div ng-repeat="tag in chosenTags">{{ tag }}</div>

</div>
</div>
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8346/) for those of you who prefers that.

How can I get rid of the added vehicles in the `<select>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to remove it from the original tags array, use [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oow4m0z6/1/)):

```
$scope.addTag = function() {
  var idx = $scope.tags.indexOf($scope.currentTag);
  if(idx >= 0) {
      $scope.chosenTags.push($scope.currentTag);
      $scope.tags.splice(idx, 1);
  }
}
```

---

To maintain the order of the `<option>`s, you can order the elements by id ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8347/)):

```
ng-options="tag.name group by tag.type for tag in tags | orderBy:'+id'"
```

Comment: JSFiddle please . . .

Comment: I did think of this, but the problem is that when you put it back again, it's in another order than it was initially. I made your changes to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8347/

Comment: @Maeh you can always order it  like so: `ng-options="tag.name group by tag.type for tag in tags | orderBy:'+id'"`